# How can I update my backing data object when the insertPre plugin returns and updates my edit area?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I am using the insertPre plugin. I don't use a SAVE button and rely on the CKEditor always keeping my back-end data in sync.

When a user enters data into the insertPre plugin and then clicks okay the contents of the insertPre are moved to the main edit area.

However I am using AngularJS and I need to have the backend data object updated when insertPre returns. Here is my solution but I am not sure it's a good one:

```
      ck.on('insertElement', function () {
            //$scope.$apply(function () {
            //    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            //});
            setTimeout(function () {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            }, 2000);
        });
```

It seems messy to wait two seconds for the textarea of CKEditor to be fully updated and then be doing an update to my backing data field.

Does anyone have any other solutions to suggest. Ideally I would like to be able to trigger on some event AFTER the insertElement has updated the screen.

Note that I have tried the following and this does not work as I guess it's not fired.

```
        ck.on('pasteState', function () {
            $scope.$apply(function () {
                ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not verified this, so test before accepting and if it fails I'll remove this A.

I'm assuming that the problem is that the change has not het actually happened when inertElement fires?

If you are using CKEditor 4.2+ you have access to a [change event](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-change). I see that insertPre is 4.1 only, but I wonder if insertElement fires the change event internally after it has finished, it to me it would seem rational. So you could try something like this and follow the console to see how often it fires.

```
ck.on('change', function () {
    console.log('change event!');
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
    });
});
```

If it's too often, just do a delay by resetting a 500ms or so timer every time this event happens and only after it gets to the end you fire update the Model - that way you won't cripple your backend/performance.